# How to check the length of array of objects here object is having array inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is my data

```
var a=[
        {
            name: "time",
            Details:[
                {value:"month",checked:true,id:1}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "product",
            Details:[
                {value:"abc",checked:true,id:2},
                {value:"abx",checked:false,id:3}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to find count of checked. In the example count is 2 how to do it in optimized way (no for loop, no filter of filter).

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard reducers here.

```js
const a=[
  {
    name: "time",
    Details:[
    {value:"month",checked:true,id:1}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "product",
    Details:[
    {value:"abc",checked:true,id:2},
    {value:"abx",checked:false,id:3}
    ]
  }
]


const total = a.reduce((total, entry) => total + entry.Details.reduce((all, inner) => all + (inner.checked === true ? 1 : 0), 0), 0)

console.log(total);
```

Once more, in a more readable fashion:

```
const total = a.reduce((total, item) => {
  // add the total to a result of adding up items in the inner arra
  return total + item.Details.reduce((innerTotal, entry) => {
    // for inner item, we add 1 if the entry is checked.
    if (entry.checked) {
      return innerTotal + 1;
    }
    // otherwise, just return the current total.
    return innerTotal;
  }, 0), // innerTotal starts at 0
 }, 0);  // and so does the outer total.
```

Comment: I would do a filter instead of the nested reduce: `reduce(
  (sum, { Details }) =>
    sum + Details.filter((detail) => detail.checked).length,
  0,
);`

Comment: Op said no filters.

Comment: Then OP doesn't make sense. Maybe OP thinks filter will mutate? Usually when someone asks something like `What's the best way to jump off a high building` I try to answer `take the elevator instead`

Comment: Possibly. Regardless of that, both solutions work ok, probably as performant as any. There are likely a few more ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks very much @Zlatko its awesome solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two `forEach()` in nested pattern:

```js
var a = [{
    name: "time",
    Details: [{
      value: "month",
      checked: true,
      id: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "product",
    Details: [{
        value: "abc",
        checked: true,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        value: "abx",
        checked: false,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  }
];

var count = 0;
a.forEach(({Details}) => Details.forEach(({checked}) => {
  if(checked){
    count++;
  }
}))
console.log(count);
```

Comment: thats helped me. is there anyway to reduce number of callbacks?

Comment: @ravireddy no, you will require two nested loops in any case

Answer (score -1):

**Try this i hope this will definitely work for you**

```
    let Count=0;
var a=[
            {
                name: "time",
                Details:[
                    {value:"month",checked:true,id:1}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "product",
                Details:[
                    {value:"abc",checked:true,id:2},
                    {value:"abx",checked:false,id:3}
                ]
            }
        ];
a.map(function(value,index){
value.Details.map(function(innerValue, innerIndex){
if( innerValue.checked==true){
Count++;
}
});
});
```

Comment: The function passed to map is usually a pure function. If you want to change a variable outside the scope of map function (=side effects so not pure) then use forEach instead.

Comment: @faraz thanks for answering in your solution nunber of callbacks are more i want avoid it

Answer (score -1):

You can combine several functions to get all details with checked value:

```
a.map(t => t.Details).flat().filter(t=>t.checked)
```

First do a map, then flat the results into one array, then filter by checked

Comment: And, if you need the count, just add length:
a.map(t => t.Details).flat().filter(t=>t.checked).length